# Como verificar a ausência de um dispositivo apontador na página em desktops?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse

Em um projeto que visa funcionar apenas em dispositivos desktop (PC de mesa ou notebook) é obrigatoriamente necessário o uso de um mouse (ou dispositivo apontador, que pode ser um touchpad).

*Caso o usuário acesse à partir de um dispositivo móvel (touch), eu faço um redirecionamento para uma página informando que a página só é funcional em um dispositivo desktop. Esse não é o problema.*

O objetivo é que, se o usuário acessar de um desktop sem um dispositivo apontador, todos os elementos da página são removidos e exibida uma caixa de aviso conforme abaixo:

```js
$(function(){
   
//   if(aqui verifico se existe um mouse!){
   
   // se não existe, removo os elementos da página
   // e aplico as propriedades abaixo:

   $("#bg").css("filter", "blur(5px)");
   $("#alerta").show();
   
//   }
   
});
```

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   height: 100vh;
}

#bg{
   position: fixed;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493246507139-91e8fad9978e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80);
   background-size: cover;
}

#alerta{
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   width: 300px;
   padding: 20px;
   background-color: #FFFEC5;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   text-align: center;
}

#alerta h2{
   margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bg"></div>
<div id="alerta">
   <h2>Não foi detectado um mouse!</h2>
   É necessário um dispositivo apontador pra usar este site. Conecte-o à uma porta USB e tecle F5.
</div>
```

O que preciso é verificar neste `if` abaixo a ausência do dispositivo apontador:

```
if(mouse não existe){
   // código pra remover todos os elementos
   // e aplicar as propriedades abaixo:
   $("#bg").css("filter", "blur(5px)");
   $("#alerta").show();
}
```

É possível verificar — e como, em JavaScript, a ausência do mouse ou do ícone do mouse na tela para então executar o código dentro do `if` citado?

Comment: Não seria mais fácil tentar detectar a primeira interação e verificar se é um mouse o touch?

Comment: No caso de ser touch, eu considerei como dispositivo móvel e faço um redirecionamento. Isso porque pode ter desktops com tela sensível ao toque. O que é preciso mesmo é que seja desktop e ter um mouse na tela.

Comment: Para saber se tem um mouse basta escutar o evento `onmousemove` porque o mouse você tem os movimentos, diferente do touch.

Comment: Mas não dá para pegar pela largura do dispositivo? Se largura for tal faça isso senão faça aquilo.

Comment: @LeAndrade Creio que a largura não determina o tipo de dispositivo. Mas o tipo de dispositivo não é problema, isso eu já fiz e funciona tranquilo.

Comment: @gato Mas o `mousemove` não só é disparado ao mover o ponteiro? Como eu faria pra detectar isso no carregamento da página se não há um mouse?

Comment: @Sam se não há um mouse você sabe que o usuário esta a usar só teclado ou touch.

Comment: @Sam da uma olhada nesta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18001239/5429980).

Comment: @gato Obg! Consegui achar a solução e postei como resposta. Obg pela ajuda!

Comment: Vou te dar uma resposta só com css, é o tempo de comer duas fatia de pizza ;D

Comment: Fiz uns testes, só consegui fazer o desktop reconhecer que está sem o mouse, mas fazer o Smartphone reconhecer que está "sem o dedo" que é o problema... Então se o cara estiver no desktop sem o mouse eu consigo mostrar ou esconder uma div, mas no smartphone não consegui, ele sempre detecta um dispositivo de entrada. Se vc quiser testar ai esse é o link do que usei. Dica, para testar depois que tirar o mouse no destop tem que abrir em outra janela, só F5 não adianta https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/any-pointer

Comment: @hugocsl É pq vc não entendeu a pergunta rs. :D Esquece smartphone, o problema é exclusivo para desktop.

Comment: Opa, então estou de volta ao jogo RSS, logo posto uma resposta, o teste é simples mas ficou bem legal eh uma técnica bem incomum mas da certo e eh pratico

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe uma solução só com CSS para isso, e vc vai usar o `@media (pointer: none);` para caso não existir uma entrada de ponteiro mostrar ou esconder a `div`

Veja na imagem, primeiro eu entro na página normal, dou um *refrash* etc, depois eu abro uma nova aba, **colo o mesmo link e desconecto meu `mouse`**, repare que o **ponteiro do `mouse` vai sumir**, ai quando aperto `enter` para entrar na página ele já não reconhece o `mouse` e mostra a `div.box`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No modelo acima eu escondo o `H1` e mostro a `div.box` caso o usuário não tenha um `mouse` conectado.

A observação fica, para caso vc quera testar vc precisa remover o mouse, e abrir o html em outra janela, pois aqui pelo menos o feedback desse tipo de `@media` não foi instantâneo, parece que o browser tem que atualizar para perceber que está sem o mouse ativo.

Código da imagem acima:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  display: none;
}

#bg{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493246507139-91e8fad9978e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(5px);
}

#alerta{
  /* display: none; */
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #FFFEC5;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

#alerta h2{
  margin-top: 0;
}

@media (pointer: none) {
  h1 {
    display: none;
  }
  .box {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Olá bem vindo, vejo que seu Rato está conectado!</h1>


<div class="box">
  <div id="bg"></div>
  <div id="alerta">
    <h2>Não foi detectado um mouse!</h2>
    É necessário um dispositivo apontador pra usar este site. Conecte-o à uma porta USB e tecle F5.
  </div>
</div>
```

Aqui está a documentação da Mozilla sobre o `@media pointer`:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/pointer

Comment: Mt bom! Daqui a pouco naõ vamos mais precisar de JS pra nada, vai ser tudo com CSS. rs

Comment: Eu queria escrever um artigo, sobre levar sempre o CSS ao limite antes de pensar em JS... CSS tem muito recurso e é subutilizado, o povo acha que é só Bootstrap e essas bobeiras. Mas tem muita coisa para explorar!

Comment: Eu tb faço isso: primeiro verifico se dá pra fazer com CSS (claro, dentro do meu conhecimento e pesquisa), quando acho que não dá MESMO, aí já parto pro JS.

Comment: Lembrando que o `matchMedia()` usado na solução do @Sam é a [API Javascript do `@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries) do CSS... Então vocês usaram o mesmo recurso por interfaces diferentes :D

Comment: @fernandosavio hahaha nem tinha notado, mas o nome realmente é o mesmo! Eu não manjo nada de JS, ainda, mas agora que vc falou reparei que parecem iguas ;)

Comment: @fernandosavio verdade.

Answer (score 3):

Existe uma API JavaScript chamada [matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) que retorna um objeto [MediaQueryList](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) com uma propriedade booleana `matches` que retorna `true` caso atenda à string da mídia especificada ou `false` caso contrário.

No caso do mouse, a string seria `(pointer:fine)`:

```
matchMedia("(pointer:fine)").matches
```

Logo, ao abrir a página, faria isso:

```
if(!matchMedia("(pointer:fine)").matches){
   $("#bg").css("filter", "blur(5px)");
   $("#alerta").show();
}
```

Ou seja, se o `matches` retornar `false`, o `if` é atendido (não existe o dispositivo apontador).

> **Obs.:** o retorno do `matchMedia()` é guardado na memória ao abrir a página. Se você conectar ou desconectar o mouse após a abertura da
>   página, o valor não muda. Será necessário fechar a aba e abri-la
>   novamente. Nesta caso, eu teria que mudar o texto da caixa de aviso
>   instruindo o usuário a fechar e abrir o site, e não apenas teclar F5.