# Como detectar se o dispositivo é touch em javascript puro?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos, touch, touch-events

Preciso adicionar eventos de touch apenas se necessário. Caso o dispositivo não seja touch, irei adicionar apenas eventos de mouse. Para isso, preciso verificar e ter um retorno. É importante, caso seja possível, que o código seja em js puro, pois quero aprender js.

Comment: Acho que é duplicada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/363967/como-verificar-a-aus%c3%aancia-de-um-dispositivo-apontador-na-p%c3%a1gina-em-desktops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode verificar se o evento *touch* que você quiser existe no objeto global `window`.

Por exemplo, se você for usar o evento `ontouchstart`, você pode fazer assim:

```
if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
  // Adicione o seu listener...
}
```

No meu caso, como estou em um dispositivo que não suporta esse evento, o bloco de código não seria executado.

Comment: Legal. Ajudou. Muito obrigado